# C++ Trie Implementation

Tags: c++, performance, trie

I recently tried a basic C++ implementation of a Trie, and was looking for some feedback on my code style/choices. In particular I was wondering if I'd made the right choice spitting the program up into header files and using classes instead of structs.

Inside the main.cpp there is a very basic string permutation function that checks, upon each permutation, whether or not the word-prefix is possible (i.e. The permutation "abx" would be terminated). This program looks for words with a minimum length of 4 characters.

[Here](https://github.com/tmck-code/WordTargetSolver/blob/master/dictionary.txt) is a dictionary file.

**DictTrie.h**

```
/**
 * File:   DictTrie.h
 * Author: freman
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "TrieNode.h"

#ifndef DICTTRIE_H
#define DICTTRIE_H

class DictTrie {

public:
    DictTrie();
    virtual ~DictTrie();
    bool containsWord(std::string str);
    bool containsPrefix(std::string str);
    void insert(std::string str);

private:
    TrieNode* root;
};

#endif  /* DICTTRIE_H */
```

**DictTrie.cpp**

```
/**
 * File:   DictTree.cpp
 * Author: freman
 *
 * Created on 18 March 2015, 8:45 AM
 */

#include "DictTrie.h"

using std::string;

DictTrie::DictTrie() {
    root = new TrieNode();
}

DictTrie::~DictTrie(){ }

bool DictTrie::containsPrefix(string str) {
    return root->containsPrefix(root, str);
}

bool DictTrie::containsWord(string str) {
    return root->containsWord(root, str);
}

void DictTrie::insert(string str) {
    root->put(root, str);
}
```

**TrieNode.h**

```
/*
 * File:   TrieNode.h
 * Author: freman
 */

#include <vector>
#include <string>

#ifndef TRIENODE_H
#define TRIENODE_H

class TrieNode {
public:
    TrieNode();
    virtual ~TrieNode();
    TrieNode(char letter);
    void put(TrieNode* root, std::string str);
    bool containsWord(TrieNode* root, std::string str);
    bool containsPrefix(TrieNode* root, std::string str);

private:
    char letter;
    bool isWord;
    std::vector<TrieNode*> children;
    void addChild(TrieNode* child);
    TrieNode* contains(TrieNode* root, std::string str);
};
#endif  /* TRIENODE_H */
```

**TrieNode.cpp**

```
/*
 * File:   TrieNode.cpp
 * Author: freman
 */

#include <iostream>
#include "TrieNode.h"

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

TrieNode::TrieNode() { }

TrieNode::~TrieNode() { }

TrieNode::TrieNode(char letter) {
    this->letter = letter;
    isWord = false;
}

bool TrieNode::containsPrefix(TrieNode* root, string str) {
    TrieNode* node = contains(root, str);
    return node != NULL;
}

bool TrieNode::containsWord(TrieNode* root, string str) {
    TrieNode* node = contains(root, str);
    if(node == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    return node->isWord;
}

TrieNode* TrieNode::contains(TrieNode* root, string str) {
    TrieNode* node = root;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        bool found = false;
        unsigned int charN = 0;
        while((charN < node->children.size()) && !found) {
            if(node->children.at(charN)->letter == str[i]) {
                found = true;
                node = node->children.at(charN);
            }
            charN++;
        }
        if(!found) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return node;
}

void TrieNode::put(TrieNode* root, string str) {
    TrieNode* node = root;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        bool found = false;
        unsigned int charN = 0;
        while((charN < node->children.size()) && !found) {
            if(node->children.at(charN)->letter == str[i]) {
                node = node->children.at(charN);
                found = true;
            }
            charN++;
        }
        if(!found) {
            node->addChild(new TrieNode(str[i]));
            node = node->children.back();
        }
    }
    node->isWord = true;
}

void TrieNode::addChild(TrieNode* child) {
    children.push_back(child);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
/**
 * File: Main.cpp
 * Author: freman
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

#include "DictTrie.h"

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int count;
int words;

void permute(string prefix, string str, DictTrie* trie) {
    if(!trie->containsPrefix(prefix)) {
        return;
    }
    ++count;
    unsigned int length = str.length();

    if(prefix.length() >= 4 && trie->containsWord(prefix)) {
        cout << "Found word: " << prefix << endl;
        ++words;
    }

    if( length != 0 ) {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            permute(prefix + str.at(i),
                    str.substr(0,i) + str.substr(i+1, length), trie);
        }
    }
}

void permuteStart(string str, DictTrie* trie) {
    permute("", str, trie);
}

DictTrie* readFile(char* filename) {
    DictTrie* trie = new DictTrie();
    string line = "";

    ifstream file(filename);

    if(file.is_open()) {
        while(getline(file, line)) {
            trie->insert(line);
        }
        file.close();
    }
    return trie;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "Test" << endl;
    count = 0;
    words = 0;

    if(argc != 3) {
        cout << "<progname> <string> <dict_file>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    DictTrie* trie = readFile(argv[2]);

    permuteStart(argv[1], trie);
    cout << "Permuted " << count << " times" << endl;
    cout << "Found " << words << " words" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First thing, memory leak if you delete `DictTrie`; use a `std::unique_ptr` to hold the `root`. Same for the `children`; use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TrieNode> >`.

There is no need for the contains functions of `TrieNode` to take a root for it's first parameter instead use `this`.

The `children` vector could be sorted by the letter to allow you to do a binary search for `O(log n)` per child, or you can use the char value as index and pre-size the vector to 256 for a `O(1)` lookup per child.

Comment: Oooh nice! Considering the dictionary I input is in alphabetical order I think the children should already be in alphabetical order as well, can't believe I didn't think of a binary search then! Genuis mate :).

Also thank you very much for the tips on memory leaks - that's the kind of stuff that I'm unfortunately quite bad at.